# Complex SQL query - Count always return 0

Tags: sql, innodb

I want to count how much users created account each month, I fount here a query - author says it worked him, but i have problem - as i said - 3rd argument is always 0.

I was trying to fix it in many ways (delete, add args) but result was the same or SQL error.

```sql
SELECT y, m, Count(ytskagamerpl_userinfo.creationdate)
FROM (
      SELECT y, m
      FROM
         (SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) y UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-1) years,
         (SELECT 1 m UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
           UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
           UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) months
    ) ym
LEFT JOIN ytskagamerpl_userinfo
    ON ym.y = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(ytskagamerpl_userinfo.creationdate))
    AND ym.m = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ytskagamerpl_userinfo.creationdate))
WHERE (y=YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m<=MONTH(CURDATE()))
      OR
      (y<YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m>MONTH(CURDATE()))
GROUP BY y, m;
```

DATABASE:

```sql
uid | creationdate (TIMESTAMP):
1   | 20.10.2018
2   | 12.11.2018
... | ..........
X   | 15.07.2019
```

PHP VAR DUMP _ https://pastebin.com/ABT5PCZn

I expect count of users created on X month 201X year, but it always returns 0,
years & months are displayed correctly.

Comment: Can you add the sample data to a SQL Fiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Your creation date is not in a timestamp format.  I think the attempted conversion involving Unix time is not correct.  What is the data types of that column?  Also, what database are you using?

Comment: InnoDB, i tried with data table TIMESTAMP and DATETIME - same result

Comment: Can you post the result for  SELECT * FROM ytskagamerpl_userinfo LIMIT 5;

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gPgzg6pZ